# PHP Guessing Number

Tags: php

This is a random number guessing game between 1 and 100.

I am stuck on the guessing number part. The code doesn't work, whatever number I put it just show me the message "Your number is lower!".I need help.

This is what I have so far.

```
<?php

$x   = rand(1, 100);
$num = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


        if ($num < $x) 
        {
            echo " Your number is lower! <br />";
        } elseif ($num > $x) 
            {
            echo " Your number is higher! <br />";
        } elseif ($num == $x) 
            {
            echo " Congratulations! You guessed the hidden number. <br />";
        } else 
            {
            echo " You never set a number! <br />";
        }




}
?>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="num">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Guess</button>
<button type="reset" name="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
</p>
```

Comment: where you are assigning number to this variable: `$num`?

Comment: Try to add this `$num = $_POST['num'];` after check your submit

Comment: You assign the `$num` as `null` or `''`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always get lower because There isn't any `value` inside you `$num`.So, You need to assigning `$num`

```
 <?php

    $x   = rand(1, 100);
    $num = '';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $num = $_POST['num']; // Add this to set value for $num variable
            if ($num < $x) 
            {
                echo " Your number is lower! <br />";
            } elseif ($num > $x) 
                {
                echo " Your number is higher! <br />";
            } elseif ($num == $x) 
                {
                echo " Congratulations! You guessed the hidden number. <br />";
            } else 
                {
                echo " You never set a number! <br />";
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the num after submit the form.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    if ($num < $x) 
    {
       echo " Your number is lower! <br />";
    } elseif ($num > $x) 
    {
        echo " Your number is higher! <br />";
    } elseif ($num == $x) 
    {
        echo " Congratulations! You guessed the hidden number. <br />";
    } else 
    {
        echo " You never set a number! <br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// value of $x is in between 1 and 100 means greater than 0 and lesser than 101
$x   = rand(1, 100);
// $num value is empty and while you attempt to compare with this this will converted to zero
$num = '';
// thus $num<$x always returns true, thats the mistake you need to assign the submitted value to the $num variable like  
$num=$_POST['num'];
// put above line just before the if($num<$x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier if you had it as a `switch/case` statement:

```
$x = rand(1,1000);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    switch($num) {
        case ($num < $x):
        echo " Your number is lower! <br />";
        break;
        case ($num > $x):
        echo " Your number is higher! <br />";
        break;
        case ($num == $x):
        echo " Congratulations! You guessed the hidden number. <br />";
        break;
        case '':
        echo " You never set a number! <br />";
        break;
    }
}
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#Nbauts2rN)

Answer (score 0):

You have set `$num = ''` (a fix empty string) and compare it with a random generated number. It's obvious that this can not work. You have to read `$_POST['num']` in PHP.

This will work, however, not as probably expected. You will need to either store the random number in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) or easier add a hidden field to the form. Otherwise the random number will change on each try.

Answer (score 0):

on 22.6.2021 i wrote a **Guess Number in Range** [0 .. aMaxIntValue] sample Web Application using PHP.
i think the following code may help you.
the code is kept in a Single PHP file.
it generates #4 HTML pages ...

- the 1st initial page is used to collect application parameters (e.g. the Max Int Number to Guess)
- the 2nd page is the Main Play Game Page where the user is asked to Guess the Secret Number or to Reset Game. this page shows the previous user guesses and some tips for the user about the guess
- the 3rd page is used to notify the user looses game (that is he has no more tries left)
- the 4th page is used to notify the user wins the game (that is the Guess was OK)
- the Number of Tries left to the User is computed using the values range [0 .. max]
- the Secret Number to Guess is a random generated integer number

this is the PHP + HTML code ...

```
    <? php ?>
    <? php ?>

<?php

    session_start();

    error_reporting (E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR);

    function ResetGame()
    {
        unset ( $_SESSION['theMaxNumber'] );
    }

    function InitGame()
    {
        $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess'] = mt_rand (0, $_SESSION['theMaxNumber']);

        $_SESSION['theMaxNumberOfTries'] = floor ( log ($_SESSION['theMaxNumber'], 2) ) + 1;

        $_SESSION['theUserTriesCount'] = 0;

        $_SESSION['thePrevGuessesString'] = '';

        $_SESSION['theUserGuess'] = 0;
    }

    function ComputeNumberOfTriesLeft()
    {
        return $_SESSION['theMaxNumberOfTries'] - $_SESSION['theUserTriesCount'];
    }

    function IsNoMoreTriesLeft()
    {
        return ComputeNumberOfTriesLeft() <= 0;
    }

    $aCanPlayGame = false;

    $aUserSubmittedGuess = false;

    $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft = false;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        if ( isset ($_REQUEST['playgame']) ) {

            $_SESSION['theMaxNumber'] = intval($_REQUEST['theMaxNumber']);

            // init game ...
            InitGame();

            $aCanPlayGame = true;

        }
        elseif ( isset ($_REQUEST['submituserguess']) ) {

            $aCanPlayGame = true;

            $aUserSubmittedGuess = true;

            $_SESSION['theUserGuess'] = intval($_REQUEST['theUserGuess']);

        }
        elseif ( isset ($_REQUEST['resetgame']) ) {

            ResetGame();

        }
        else {
            ResetGame();
        }

    }
    else {
        ResetGame();
    }

    // check a play

    $aUserShouldTryLower = false;
    $aUserShouldTryHigher = false;

    $aUserWins = false;

    $aUserLooses = false;

    if ($aCanPlayGame) {

        $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft = IsNoMoreTriesLeft();

        if ( ! $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft ) {

            // user have tries left

            if ($aUserSubmittedGuess) {

                // check user guess ...
                $aUserGuess = intval($_SESSION['theUserGuess']);

                if ( $aUserGuess > $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess'] ) {

                    $aUserShouldTryLower = true;

                }
                elseif ( $aUserGuess < $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess'] ) {

                    $aUserShouldTryHigher = true;

                }
                else {

                    $aUserWins = true;

                    // also reset game
                    ResetGame();

                }

                // add the current guess to the prev guesses string
                $_SESSION['thePrevGuessesString'] .= $_SESSION['theUserGuess'] . ' ';

                // increase the user tries count
                ++ $_SESSION['theUserTriesCount'];

                // check tries count
                if ( ! $aUserWins ) {

                    $aIsNoMoreTriesLeft = IsNoMoreTriesLeft();

                    if ($aIsNoMoreTriesLeft) {
                        // this was the last try

                        // no more tries left
                        $aUserLooses = true;

                        // also reset game
                        ResetGame();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        else {
            // no more tries left
            $aUserLooses = true;

            // also reset game
            ResetGame();
        }

    }

?>

<?php if ($aUserLooses): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Sorry, you loose the game</p>
    <p>the Number to Guess was <?php echo $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess']; ?></p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="resetgame" value="reset game">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php elseif ($aUserWins): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Congrats, you Win the Game</p>
    <p>the Number to Guess was <?php echo $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess']; ?></p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="resetgame" value="reset game">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php elseif ($aCanPlayGame): ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>the Max Number is <?php echo $_SESSION['theMaxNumber']; ?></p>
    <p>Guess a Number in the Range [ 0 .. <?php echo ($_SESSION['theMaxNumber']); ?> ]</p>
    <p>[DEBUG] the secret number to guess is <?php echo $_SESSION['theNumberToGuess']; ?></p>
    <p>you have <?php echo ComputeNumberOfTriesLeft(); ?> tries left</p>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="theUserGuess">Enter your Guess: </label>
        <input type="text" id="theUserGuess" name="theUserGuess">
        <input type="submit" name="submituserguess" value="Guess">
        <input type="submit" name="resetgame" value="reset game">
    </form>
    <p>Prev Guesses: <?php echo $_SESSION['thePrevGuessesString']; ?> </p>
    <p>
        <?php
            if ($aUserShouldTryLower) {
                echo 'you should try a lower < guess';
            }
            elseif ($aUserShouldTryHigher) {
                echo 'you should try a higher > guess';
            }
            else {
                echo 'no guess';
            }
        ?>
    </p>

</body>
</html>

<?php else: ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Guess a Number from (0) to ... </p>
    <form method="post">
        <input id="theMaxNumber" name="theMaxNumber">
        <input type="submit" name="playgame" value="play game">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php endif; ?>

    <? php ?>
```

that's all folks ...